# How to add color to a mat-card with angular

Tags: html, angular

I am just looking to add more color to this card how would I do that?
Here is my current code for my mat-card:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <h2>Log In</h2>
<!--      <mat-error *ngIf="f.">-->
<!--        The username and password were not recognised-->
<!--      </mat-error>-->
      <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="f.username.errors">
          Please provide a valid username address
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
        <input matInput type="Password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="f.password.errors">
          Please provide a valid password
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-fab color="primary">Login</button>
    </form>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[image: Current state of my mat-card]

Comment: You can add the color in your `css` | `scss` file either by using the `mat-card` directly or creating a class to use. Though there are some pre-defined class for material component.

Comment: In addition to what @BelleZaid wrote, remember to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.NONE` to your component definition in typescript. Checkout [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)